# Node.JS/Express - Why does A-Sync seem to go in a random order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have recently started using Node.js/Express. I understand an A-Sync call must complete before it can move on. In my code there are three different end points I need to hit.

As I have taken A-Sync into account I have tried to code it so it does them in order they are presented.

However it hits the first end point, then the third and then the second. I understand it must be an issue in my code however I've been at this for hours.

Where have I gone wrong? Why does it leave the second endpoint till last?

```
app.get("/start/:origin/:destination", function ( reqt, resp ) {
var origin = reqt.params.origin
var destination = reqt.params.destination
var url = 'http://localhost:5000/maps/' + origin + '/' + destination 

var rate;
var overallDis;
var aRoadDis;

var data;
http.get(url, res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8')
    res.on('data', function(body){
        data = JSON.parse(body)
        overallDis = data["distance"]
        aRoadDis = data["ARoads"]
    })
})

var driver;
http.get("http://localhost:4000/lowestRate/", res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8')
    res.on('data', function(body){
        driver = JSON.parse(body)
        rate = driver.rate
        console.log(rate)
    })

})

var totalPrice = 0
http.get("http://localhost:6000/surge/:" + rate + "/:" + overallDis + "/:" + aRoadDis, res => {
    // console.log(overallDis)
    // console.log(aRoadDis)
    // console.log(rate)
    res.setEncoding('utf8')
    res.on('data', function(body){
        console.log(body)
        totalPrice += parseInt(body)
    })
    console.log(totalPrice)
})

})
```

Comment: For searching for your own answer, everyone else uses "async" as the term, not "A-Sync"...

Comment: I don't know where you've got the idea that "an A-Sync call must complete before it can move on". That's pretty much the opposite of what's actually the case! An asynchronous function will return almost immediately, but the callback code will only be executed when the asynchronous functionality (in this case the HTTP calls) is complete. The order of the results is probably determined by how long the "remote" code takes to execute.

Comment: use with `await`

Comment: Thank you all! Didn't realise my knowledge was so wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand an A-Sync call must complete before it can move on.

This is actually not the case. When you make your HTTP request it will make that request and move on. In your case it will continue on to make the next two HTTP requests.

After it gets a response it will fire the corresponding [callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). Your callbacks will fire in the order that you get responses to your HTTP requests.

Here's a nice link for learning about the Javascript event loop.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Hope that helps!

PS: If you'd like to wait for one request to finish before moving on to the rest I would suggest [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
app.get("/start/:origin/:destination", function ( reqt, resp ) {
    const origin = reqt.params.origin
    const destination = reqt.params.destination
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/maps/' + origin + '/' + destination
    const totalPrice = 0

    const firstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      http.get(url, res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8')
        res.on('data', function(body){
          data = JSON.parse(body)
          resolve({
            overallDis: data["distance"],
            aRoadDis: data["ARoads"]
          });
        })
      })
    });

    const secondPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      http.get("http://localhost:4000/lowestRate/", res => {
        res.setEncoding('utf8')
        res.on('data', function(body){
          const driver = JSON.parse(body)
          const rate = driver.rate
          console.log(rate)
          resolve(rate);
        })
      })
    });

    Promise.all([firstPromise, secondPromise]).then((values) => {
      // This will fire after both promises have called resolve()
      const overallDis = values[0].overallDis;
      const aRoadDis   = values[0].aRoadDis;
      const rate       = values[1];

      http.get("http://localhost:6000/surge/:" + rate + "/:" + overallDis + "/:" 
        + aRoadDis, res => {
          // console.log(overallDis)
          // console.log(aRoadDis)
          // console.log(rate)
          res.setEncoding('utf8')
          res.on('data', function(body){
            console.log(body)
            totalPrice += parseInt(body)
          })
          console.log(totalPrice)
      })
    });
})
```

Answer (score -1):

As is mentioned in the other answers, your interpretation of async is the wrong way around: synchronous calls block the execution of following code, whereas asynchronous calls do not.

If you want to go through your operations in order, but they actually are asynchronous, the easiest method is using callbacks. This is doable for smaller call stacks, but it is not called callback-hell for nothing.

The best way would be to wrap the async calls in Promises and then using the async/await structure to order them in a synchronous fashion. This could look something like this.

```
async function (req, res) {
    let op_1_result = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ... do your async operation and finally call
        resolve(response);
    });

    ... do your other operations in the same fashion

    let op_n_result = await new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ... do your async operation and finally call
        resolve(response);
    });
    return op_n_result;
}
```